# Gradient in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, gradient

Here is my css (for this gradient the code was copied from colorzilla). Nothing too special. If i remove all the gradient parts and stay with a solid color, the colored stripe renders in IE8 just fine. But the gradient is not displaying (in chrome everything looks correct). How to fix this? Thnks.

```
.hdr:after {
   content: " ";
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   min-width: 960px;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   height: 3px;
   background: #e7eff3;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #e7eff3 0%, #1d667a 50%, #e7eff3 100%);
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #e7eff3), color-stop(50%, #1d667a), color-stop(100%, #e7eff3));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e7eff3 0%, #1d667a 50%, #e7eff3 100%);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #e7eff3 0%, #1d667a 50%, #e7eff3 100%);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #e7eff3 0%, #1d667a 50%, #e7eff3 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(to right, #e7eff3 0%, #1d667a 50%, #e7eff3 100%);
   filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e7eff3', endColorstr='#e7eff3', GradientType=1);
   -ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e7eff3', endColorstr='#e7eff3',GradientType=1 )';
}
```

Comment: should not it be :`-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e7eff3', endColorstr='#e7eff3',GradientType=1 );`

Comment: May be the problem is with pseudo elements, and there is no css solution to set a gradient background to :after element?